# Recursive closure as function parameter “cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements”

Tags: rust

This question is more complex than [Closure as function parameter “cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627673/closure-as-function-parameter-cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-due-to-confl).

There's a recursive closure which move environmental variable into it.

The code below works, [tool](https://github.com/Stebalien/tool-rs) is a grab-bag of useful functions for functional programming includes [making recursive closure](https://docs.rs/tool/0.2.1/tool/fn.fix.html):

```
extern crate tool;
use tool::prelude::*;
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let a = Cell::new(false);

    let fib = fix(move |f, x| {
        a.set(true);
        if x == 0 || x == 1 {
            x
        } else {
            // `f` is `fib`
            f(x - 1) + f(x - 2)
        }
    });

    println!("{}", fib(10));
}
```

I want to know is it possible to pass that closure to a function, then call that function in that closure, the code below throws an error.

```
extern crate tool;
use tool::prelude::*;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let a = RefCell::new(false);

    let fib = fix(move |f, x| {
        *a.borrow_mut() = true;
        if x == 0 || x == 1 {
            x
        } else {
            // `f` is `fib`
            b(Box::new(f), x - 1) + f(x - 2)
        }
    });

    fn b (c: Box<Fn(u64) -> u64>, n: u64) -> u64 {
        c(n)
    }

    println!("{}", b(Box::new(fib), 10));
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:14:24
   |
14 |             b(Box::new(f), x - 1) + f(x - 2)
   |                        ^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 8:19... 
  --> src/main.rs:8:19
   |
8  |       let fib = fix(move |f, x| {
   |  ___________________^
9  | |         *a.borrow_mut() = true;
10 | |         if x == 0 || x == 1 {
11 | |             x
...  |
15 | |         }
16 | |     });
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected &dyn std::ops::Fn(u64) -> u64
              found &dyn std::ops::Fn(u64) -> u64
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::Fn(u64) -> u64 + 'static)>
              found std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(u64) -> u64>
```

Comment: Just [removing the `Box`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=61b3bad332c166778cd73553354ab791&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) seems to work for me. Is that what you want?

Comment: It works for me too. But I found what I need is still more complex than it. I don't know whether I need to take a break, or keep asking question. I'm new to Rust, and I'm tired.

Comment: What I want is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=044651be795dc090ce740e7ca6f7a437

Comment: It looks like you are mixing `fn`, `dyn Fn` and maybe `impl Fn`. I'm not familiar with `tool` but messing around, [this version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd576c6aa83f8bdf5b955dc6c5fdbe23&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) compiles.

Comment: I will learn them soon, Hi I change the gist just now when you are helping me. Shall you check it again: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=044651be795dc090ce740e7ca6f7a437

Comment: Other than the obvious typo in the return type, [the correction would be similar to the previous one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=efffbfc0354f8cbe2011feb771339e9e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing several concepts here. First of all you must understand the difference between these:

1. `fn(A) -> B`
2. `impl Fn(A) -> B` or `T: Fn(A) -> B`
3. `&dyn Fn(A) -> B`
4. `Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B>`

Number 1 is the type of a pointer to a function, just like in C.

Number 2 is a generic type that implements the *function* trait `Fn`, that is a type that is *callable*.

Number 3 is a dynamic reference to a callable object (the `dyn` keyword is optional).

Number 4 is a *trait object*, that is a boxed callable object with the real type erased.

Now look at the definition of [`tool::fix`](https://docs.rs/tool/0.2.1/tool/fn.fix.html):

```
pub fn fix<A, B, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(A) -> B 
where
    F: Fn(&Fn(A) -> B, A) -> B,
```

From that you see that `fix` uses number 2 for the `f` parameter, but number 3 for the `A` parameter of `f`. Also, it returns number 2.

The tricky part here is that `f` is a function that takes a function as argument. The `f` itself can be any of any kind that implements `Fn`, but the first argument of that function must be of `&dyn Fn` kind.

Your original error comes from trying to box a `&dyn Fn(A) -> B`, but you cannot do that generically, because such a value may contain references, and `Box` requires a `'static` type.

But with all that in mind you can carefully write your function without using `Box`, so your problem just disappears, and the result is nicer ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=313cb1d53170ab2a14b7caa7f3ba21a3&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
fn main() {
    fn wrap (wrap_fn: impl Fn(&dyn Fn(u64) -> u64, u64) -> u64) -> impl Fn(u64) -> u64 {
        let a = RefCell::new(false);

        let fib = fix(move |f, x| {
            *a.borrow_mut() = true;
            if x == 0 || x == 1 {
                x
            } else {
                // `f` is `fib`
                wrap_fn(f, x - 1) + wrap_fn(f, x - 2)
            }
        });  

        fib
    }

    fn b (c: &dyn Fn(u64) -> u64, n: u64) -> u64 {
        c(n)
    }

    println!("{}", (wrap(b))(10));
}
```

Comment: In your first comment, [removing the Box](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=61b3bad332c166778cd73553354ab791), I don't see any dynamic references,`fn b (c: impl Fn(u64) -> u64, n: u64)` just works out, why?

Comment: @周汉成: Ah, but the code in that comment does have a dynamic reference. You don't see it because the type is deduced by the compiler: the `f` argument in the lambda function. If you check its type, it is `&dyn Fn(_) -> _`. Which is expected, because that is what `fix()` needs.